# How can I recover an SVN repository from 2013

Tags: svn

When I try to dump the repo, I get "revision file (r2) lacks trailing newline". This happens for any revision from 2 upto 1258. I believe this is because SVN format has changed.

Is there any way to recover the files?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with repository filesystem format changes. Your repository is corrupt and most likely the revision files are blank (e.g., actual content was replaced with zeros). This problem could occur due to a disk failure.

Your best option now is to restore a backup.

Comment: Thanks - examining the files there doesn't seem to be any data!